# Hibernate is not updating a database record

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, sql-update, deadlock

I'm trying to update an existing object from the database using Hibernate.

I run the code, and it doesn't give me any errors, but it's also not updating the database. I searched for the problem but I can't see where is my mistake.

Here is my function from `userDAO` class:

```
public void updateYear(int id, int year) {
            try {

                Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
                SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
                Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
                Transaction transaction = null;
                transaction = session.beginTransaction();


            String hql = "UPDATE User u set u.year= :year WHERE u.id= :id";
            Query query=session.createQuery(hql).setParameter("year", year).setParameter("id", id);
            int result = query.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("Rows affected: " + result+"!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");


            transaction.commit();
             session.close();

            } catch (HibernateException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                System.out.println("error");
            }

        }
```

And here is just how I call it:

```
UserDAO u = new UserDAO();
        u.updateYear(1,6);
```

The result is something like this:

```
aa DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter: throwQueryException() : no errors
aa DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter: throwQueryException() : no errors
aa DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL: 
    update
        user 
    set
        year=? 
    where
        id=?
Hibernate: 
    update
        user 
    set
        year=? 
    where
        id=?
```

Also sometimes, I recieve this error, but not exactly after running, I find it weird:

```
aa DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: could not execute statement [n/a]
java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4096)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4028)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2490)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2683)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2144)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2444)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2362)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2347)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:205)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.exec.BasicExecutor.doExecute(BasicExecutor.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.exec.BasicExecutor.execute(BasicExecutor.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.executeUpdate(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:437)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(HQLQueryPlan.java:374)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.executeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1510)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doExecuteUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1526)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.executeUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1504)
    at dao.UserDAO.updateYear(UserDAO.java:160)
    at Main.main(Main.java:52)
```

In case u need, this is my hibernate cfg:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/licenta</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>

        <mapping resource="user.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="chapter.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="comments.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="problems.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="questions.hbm.xml"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I mention that other operations like inserting or reading users it's working properly.

So, any ideas on how can I do this update?

Comment: Do you have a User POJO? If so, I think Hibernate can't find a User instance that matches your condition (id=1) and consequently doesn't update anything. Usually you can use Session.get(User.class, id) to retrieve the User instance and update that instance directly (Session.update(user) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many things you are doing wrong here:

1. Why are you creating the `SessionFactory` every time you need to call `updateYear`? `SessionFactory is an expensive object which should be created during application bootstrap and reused afterward. Use Spring or Java EE for that and inject the` SesisonFactory` as a dependency.
2. If an Exception is thrown, you never call `transaction.rollback()` so locks can be kept until for the duration of the default transaction timeout.
3. Also, `session.close()` should be called in a `finally` block. Check out this Template method on the [High-Performance Java Persistence GitHub repository](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/high-performance-java-persistence/blob/master/core/src/test/java/com/vladmihalcea/book/hpjp/util/AbstractTest.java#L386).
4. Why do you call `UPDATE` manually when you use Hibernate? This is how you should do it:

   ```
    User user = session.get(User.class, id);
    user.setYear(year);
   ```

   The dirty checking mechanism will take care of the UPDATE for you so there's no need to call `saveOrUpdate`, `update`, or `merge` for a managed entity.
5. As you can see from the logs, the `UPDATE` was issued but you got the `java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction` because a concurrent transaction has already acquired the lock on this particular record or for a range of records including this one. If that's the case, you just need to retry your transaction upon deadlock. You can even use an auto-retry mechanism.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all those explanations. I got the code to work without those anyway, but it's far from being a good implementation. I will really read everything you suggested me and do the changes acordingly. Thank you!